# How to parse a webpage with no <P> or </P> tags in R?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using `rvest` to parse html pages. I'm hoping to extract the paragraphs from the page:

```
txtfile %>% paste(collapse=" ") %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('p')
```

However, here's an example of a webpage that does not work because (my best guess) it does not have paragraph tags: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1001039/000100103916000378/0001001039-16-000378.txt

How would I be able to parse something like this in R?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi yes I am!

Comment: `read_html('path/to/txtfile/here') %>% html_text()` ...if you don't care about getting _all_ the text at once

Comment: It's just text. Look for empty lines if read in with readLines or "\n\n" if pasted as text.

Comment: There's a weird text header, but this is an html document that can be parsed with `rvest`. It's not clear what you are looking to extract from this document, and the document is too big to guess.

Comment: @cory I'd like to get all the text in the document, stripping away the html tags.